# Switch between multiple windows on different desktops on OSX

Tags: windows, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I am on BigSur and have Google Chrome on multiple desktops. I want to easily switch between these windows but CMD+Tab only allows to switch between different apps. CMD+' allows only to switch between multiple windows of the same app on the same desktop. Apparently there's the option to press the down key to iterate through other windows when in CMD+Tab mode. But that only works if the windows are on the same desktop as well.

What's the easiest way to quickly switch? Currently I need to go to the bar and click the app icon.

Comment: You keep hold of Cmd to do the down arrow trick - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app/193938#193938

Comment: Thanks yeah I know, still doesn't work though in Big Sur.

Comment: It's worked for years & still works in Monterey, so I doubt it's skipped an OS.

Comment: Not saying it's generally not working but it's not working for me. As said, as soon as I press the arrow key the pop-up just closes.

Comment: Have you checked your custom key commands for clashes?

Comment: I found out the down key shortcut works BUT only when the windows are on the same desktop. If they are on different desktops it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using fullscreen? Fullscreen kills much of Spaces' functionality. Personally, I avoid it entirely. This is already mentioned in the linked answer, though I have now re-cast it to emphasise this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With windows the default behavior is to show all seperate chrome windows side by side. Using some free macOS software, this would allow you to just CMD+Tab to those seperate Chrome instances.

There are free programs availible for Macos that give you more control over CMD+Tab behavior and how it looks. (More similair to how windows does it)

The programs i would recommend are: (one of these)

- HyperSwitch (from Bahoom)
- AltTab (Dont worry it does CMD+Tab just fine)

Some notable features

- Only display CMD+Tab window on monitor that currently has the mouse on it.
- Option to only show windows from that specific monitor (where mouse is)
- Option to show windows from different workspaces / desktops on macos

Comment: Well it's not native, but unless it works like such, this seems to be the best solution. Thanks!

Comment: Update: been using AltTab for some time now and it does exactly what I need